# Exclude weight of free product on cart

Tags: cart, quote, coupon, free-gift

I'm trying to caltulate the total wight of products in cart and here is my code:

```
//If we have no weight, try to calculate this
$weight = 0;
if ($quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight() == null ||
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight() == 0 ||
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight() == '') {

    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $itemWeight = $item->getWeight();
        if ($itemWeight != null) {
            $weight += $itemWeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is I have free/bonus products in the cart and this free product has weight. The above code just add the weight of the free product as well. I want to know is there a way I can exclude the weight of the free product in my cart. Or how can I filter the free/bonus products on magento using the Singleton.

Comment: Why not just check the price of your products (i guess price is 0?) before adding the weight: `if ($itemWeight != null && $item->getPrice>0){ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

So as commented by Anna you could filter by price

```
if ($itemWeight != null && $item->getPrice() > 0) {
    $weight += $itemWeight;
}
```

But I would suggest that maybe this would not be the best idea. If the "free" product has a specific sku or attribute that marks it as "free" then I would use this as part of the check.